# PHP DateTime does not correctly calculate time component when adding across DST boundaries

Tags: php, datetime, time, timezone, timezone-offset

Consider the following code

```
$participantTriggerDate = new \DateTime('2019-06-14 09:40:00.000000', new DateTimeZone('US/Central'));
$dateInterval = new \DateInterval('P150D');

$newDate = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromMutable($participantTriggerDate);
$newDate = $newDate->add($dateInterval);

echo(json_encode([
    'participantTriggerDate' => $participantTriggerDate,
    'newDate' => $newDate,
]));
```

This code produces the following output:

```
{
  "participantTriggerDate": {
    "date": "2019-06-14 09:40:00.000000",
    "timezone_type": 3,
    "timezone": "US/Central"
  },
  "newDate": {
    "date": "2019-11-11 09:40:00.000000",
    "timezone_type": 3,
    "timezone": "US/Central"
  }
}
```

However because 150 days past 2019-06-14 crosses a DST boundary, shouldn't PHP subtract and hour from the time? I thought that PHP took care of all the messy DST stuff under the hood. Is there a way for me to correctly calculate this time? From what I've read it looks like the recommended answer is to convert everything to UTC and do the calculations there. I would like to avoid this if possible. I figured PHP would be smart enough to know that a DST boundary was crossed when I pass a timezone into DateTime creation.

Comment: `DateInterval()` adjusts for DST, so if you say that it should be `0H`, it will be the same time of day, regardless of DST.

Comment: This is usually what one wants. When you say you want to do something N days later, it means at the same time of day.

Comment: @Barmar I figured by not specifying a time component, that PHP would know that adding 150 days to the date would result in crossing a DST boundary, and would appropriately adjust the time. This doesn't seem to be the case. Is there something I need to add to the DateInterval string to get PHP to calculate the time component properly? In this current form, its obvious that PHP's DateInterval is not calculating DST changes correctly when added to a date.

Comment: Why do you say it's not adjusting? The time is `09:40` in both dates.

Comment: Because 150 days after 2019-06-14 in the US/Central timezone passes a Daylight Savings Time boundary meaning that adding 150 days results in the timezone falling back an hour. So technically speaking, +150 days to this date is actually +149 days and 23 hours.

Comment: Because DST is not explicit across locations and timezones, I'm trying to figure out why PHP doesn't handle this under the hood for me as I assumed it did.

Comment: The point is that it adjusts automatically, so you don't notice the extra or missing hour. 150 days is not the same as 150*24 hours.

Comment: My point is that it does not adjust the time accordingly. If you run the code above you will see it does not adjust the time component of the newDate to reflect that it is in a different DST for that timezone. If PHP were doing this conversion under the hood for me newDate would have a time of 8:40:00

Comment: If it had a time of 8:40 it wouldn't be the same time, it would be an hour different. That's what you would get if you added 3600 hours instead of 150 days.

Comment: Notice that the timezone is `US/Central`. That means that times are shown in whatever is the appropriate state of daylight or standard time applies on the date, they're not shown in the current timezone.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding what I am saying here. In some places, DST happens, and in others it doesn't. When setting timezones on a PHP date object, PHP automatically determines the changes across DST. If you convert from a timezone thats in DST to a timezone thats out of DST. PHP will do this math for you and return the proper time. In this case, I am adding a date interval that causes the DATE to change from inside DST, to outside DST. Adding 150 days to the date means that the time has actually changed in that timezone.

Comment: I understand that. And what I'm trying to tell you is that when it sees that it crosses a DST boundary, it automatically adds or subtracts an hour to keep the time of day the same, because adding multiples of days shouldn't change the time.

Comment: I was hoping that DST calculations happened automatically when adding a date interval that caused a date object to cross a DST boundary. As maintaining this myself would be problematic and prone to breakage. Adding 150 days to this date isn't adding exactly 150 days because of DST

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202173/discussion-between-barmar-and-xenology).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add whole days, PHP produces the same time of day, even if DST has changed. If you want to add a time interval without making this adjustment, you need to add hours rather than days. Multiply the number of days by `24` to get this.

```
$dateInterval = new \DateInterval('PT3600H'); // 3600 = 150*24
```